# Hover over image to get a box with multiple links in html/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I'd like to make it so that when users hover over a picture on my website, they get a grey box the same size as the picture, and inside the grey box is a list; each of the items on the list link to a different site. I don't know how to do this; I can only find tutorials on how to replace images with other images when users hover over them. I don't want that; I want to replace the image with a box that itself contains multiple links. I don't need a specific answer so much as a general idea about how this can be done. How do you developers do this?

What may make this more complicated is that I would like to line up three pictures just like this in a horizontal row; for each picture, users can hover over them and then click on an item in the list.

(I'm new to html and css, and I'm willing to use JavaScript if that's the best solution. Thank you in advance for your help!)

Comment: Learn these CSS concepts and you can do this with no JavaScript: `opacity`, `:hover` and `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the html:

```
<div id="container">
  <img id="image"/>
  <div id="overlay">
    <a href="www.site1.com">Link 1</a><br>
    <a href="www.site2.com">Link 2</a><br>
    <a href="www.site3.com">Link 3</a><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
#container {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
#image {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background:black;//should be url of your image
}
#overlay {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:gray;
  opacity:0;
}
#overlay:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/8pjw8L5r/)

Answer (score 0):

On wrapper hover,just show the div containing the lists else it should be hidden.Here is the working example.
HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg" class="showDiv" width="200px" height="200px" alt="image" />
<div class="showOnHover">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed3.jpg">link1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg">link2</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed1.jpg">link3</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
}
.wrapper:hover .showOnHover{
  display:block !important;
}
.showOnHover{
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   height:100%;
}
```